# Error passing vector argument to function argument

Tags: matlab

I am getting an error "not enough input arguments" when calling a function that was passed as an argument using two other arguments.

```
>>q = [.33 .423 .523 1.023 .6 1.047]';
>>NewtRaphDynamics(q,0,PA1_PHI,PA1_Jacobian)
Error using PA1_PHI (line 8)
Not enough input arguments.
```

where PA1_PHI and PA1_Jacobian are function files in the matlab directory. The function NewtRaphDynamics is thus:

```
function [qout D] = NewtRaphDynamics(iq,t,PHI,Jac,err,it)
%... code setting defaults for 'err' and 'it' if they are not specified ...
norm = @(what) sqrt(what'*what);

iter = 0;
iq
pause

% Solving for position problem q
while iter < it
    iPHI = PHI(iq,t);
    D = Jac(iq);
    if(norm(iPHI) < err), break, end
    deliq = - D\iPHI;
    iq = iq + deliq;
    iter = iter + 1;
end

qout = [t iq'];
```

the function call throwing the error is:

```
function PHI = PA1_PHI(q,t)

PHI = zeros(6,1);

PHI(1) = q(1) - .5*cos(q(3)) + .2*sin(q(3));
PHI(2) = q(2) - .5*sin(q(3)) - .2*cos(q(3));
PHI(3) = q(4) - .4*cos(q(6)) - (q(1) + .7*cos(q(3)) + .1*sin(q(3)));
PHI(4) = q(5) - .4*sin(q(6)) - (q(2) + .7*sin(q(3)) - .1*cos(q(3)));
PHI(5) = q(4) + .4*cos(q(6)) - 1.6;
PHI(6) = q(5) + .4*sin(q(6)) - (1 - .2*cos(2*pi*t)); % appended constraint
```

Comment: `NewtRaphDynamics(iq,t,PHI,Jac,err,it)` requires 6 input arguments, but when you call it using `NewtRaphDynamics(q,0,PA1_PHI,PA1_Jacobian)` you are only giving it 4 input arguments. You need to give it `err` and `it` as well.

Comment: The immediate problem is you are passing the return value  of `PA1_PHI` as an argument to the function. What you should be doing is passing the function handle of `PA1_PHI`.

Comment: @David He commented out the code that handles `err` and `it` as optional parameters.

Comment: Yep, when calling the function, `NewtRaphDynamics(q,0,PA1_PHI,PA1_Jacobian)` should instead be `NewtRaphDynamics(q,0,@PA1_PHI,@PA1_Jacobian)`.

Comment: @Setsu exactly what I was looking for. In retrospect would've been easy to find an answer had I known what to search :\

Comment: @David right, as soon as I read Setsu's comment I knew what to look for.

thanks for the help guys